# Add date to current date mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I have to find out what items in my warehouse are expiring in next 30 days. 
I wrote the following query

```
SELECT ItemName, ExpirationDate, 
FROM table 
WHERE ExpirationDate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and SYSDATE()
```

I have also tried `CURDATE()`. `ExpirationDate` is stored as `'DATE'`
The query doesn't return any results. I know for sure that there are items expiring in next 30 days. 
I've also tried giving a large number as `INTERVAL 30000 DAY` too. I do not get any results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Mysql is looking for the first item in the `BETWEEN` clause to be the lower value, and the second value to be the higher value.

```
SELECT ItemName, ExpirationDate FROM table 
WHERE ExpirationDate BETWEEN SYSDATE() AND DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Comment: Could have never guessed that. I usually see the docs when I get an error.